# Problem Finding Server error trying to go online after bootup

Tags: wireless, firefox, internet

My Ubuntu 16.10 on my Panasonic Toughbook CF-73 does this occasionally when I boot up and launch Firefox browser (also, Thunderbird email can't get email). The Wifi is connected, but "Problem Finding Server" error persists - NOTHING FIXES IT - it appears to be a basic problem with this open source chaos and ".local" domains that our Uverse occasionally assigns at first (tried to fix Avahi-daemon, but this is only a side effect of a greater systemic issue). I have to just hold down the on button until it 'lets go', then reboot and see if THIS TIME it connects - usually it does, but some times I have to force power off again and reboot again. My Vista 64-bit occasionally gets this way but it resolves itself shortly and I can go online - with Ubuntu it NEVER resolves unless you reboot - just the same "Problem Finding Server" vague error message on the browser.... just crash down and try again. JUNK software... How to fix this issue?

btw - I tried "Alt + SysRq + R" and nothing - the screen just stares back... (FYI)

Would upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04 possibly fix this issue?

Funny - my NOOK color never has this problem that my VistaUbuntu does... it goes online with no issues ever.

Results of `ping 192.168.1.254`

```
PING 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=2.28 ms 
64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=6.25 ms
...
64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=21 ttl=255 time=2.29 ms

--- 192.168.1.254 ping statistics --- 
21 packets transmitted, 21 received, 0% packet loss, time 20028ms 
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.849/2.736/6.250/1.012 ms
```

> Does it give you the "Problem Finding Server" message when you try to connect to a particular server, or does it say that for anything on the internet?

It doesn't happen every time I boot up and try going online, just most of the time, BUT  I just found out that if I open a terminal and then I do `sudo killall dnsmasq` while Firefox is displaying "Problem Finding Server", then reload the page... and I'm online :-> ...doesn't 'fix' the problem, but at least it unlocks whatever is stopping internet access without a complete reboot, or worse multiple reboots... I guess it's on to being a guinea pig for 17.04 when I got upgraded.

Results of `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp6s2 proto static metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp6s2 proto kernel scope link src 
192.168.1.86 metric 600
```

Results of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000 
    link/ether 00:0b:97:31:92:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
3: wlp6s2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000 
    link/ether 00:13:ce:44:4c:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
    inet 192.168.1.86/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlp6s2 
        valid_lft 85976sec preferred_lft 85976sec 
    inet6 2602:306:358b:2df0:d81c:cace:8e01:5065/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
        valid_lft 604375sec preferred_lft 85375sec 
    inet6 2602:306:358b:2df0:f93e:83e5:406b:7a61/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic 
        valid_lft 2591575sec preferred_lft 604375sec 
    inet6 fe80::e107:e686:249:73e3/64 scope link 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Oh, and the connection is wireless.

Comment: Does this for ANY webpage I try to goto (seems stuck in 'local only' mode) - until I run "sudo killall dnsmasq", then I can goto any webpage for the rest of the time (well, until I boot up again and it starts over...)

I can goto the the uverse gateway (192.168.1.254) while the error exists (ie while in 'local only' mode) or I can go there after running the workaround... not sure what ping is....

Comment: OK - ping... interesting - this is what happens either way:
PING 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=2.28 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=6.25 ms
... edited out lots of lines - too many to post?
64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=21 ttl=255 time=2.29 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.254 ping statistics ---
21 packets transmitted, 21 received, 0% packet loss, time 20028ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.849/2.736/6.250/1.012 ms

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. According to my best guess you can't open web sites over a WiFi network. Then there's something about domain names ending in `.local`. Then you write about black screens and force-rebooting your computer. Could you please [edit] your question to explain 1) how the three are related, 2) *what exactly* you did to run into each of these issues and 3) what your question(s) are? It would help if you used proper punctuation and paragraphs and/or lists to format your post to make it more accessible. Thanks.

Comment: As for your comments, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: OK - I'll just use the "sudo killall dnsmasq" to reset whatever and go with that... thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

So you have an intermittent network problem... Does your computer only have the wifi connection, or does it have a wired connection as well?

Quoting your troubleshooting output:

```
ip route

>default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp6s2 proto static metric 600 
>192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp6s2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.86 metric 600 

ip addr

>1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
>    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
>    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo 
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
>2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000 
>    link/ether 00:0b:97:31:92:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
>3: wlp6s2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000 
>    link/ether 00:13:ce:44:4c:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
>    inet 192.168.1.86/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlp6s2
>        valid_lft 85976sec preferred_lft 85976sec 
>    inet6 2602:306:358b:2df0:d81c:cace:8e01:5065/64 scope global
```

shows that your wireless connection is up, connected to network 192.168.1.0/24, with a DHCP address of 192.168.1.86 and going through gateway 192.168.1.254 to connect to the internet. Your default route is set to use that gateway.

So far, nothing looks wrong. Does it give you the "Problem Finding Server" message when you try to connect to a particular server, or does it say that for anything on the internet?

Can you ping gateway 192.168.1.254 when you are stuck in this state?

Comment: First - doesn't happen every time I boot up and try going online - just most of the time - BUT, I just found out that if I open a terminal and then I do "sudo killall dnsmasq" while firefox is displaying "Problem Finding Server", then reload page...and I'm online :->
...doesn't 'fix' the problem, but at least it unlocks whatever is stopping internet access without a complete reboot, or worse multiple reboots.... sheesh, guess it's on to being guinea pig for 17.04 when I get upgraded :-\

Comment: ip route sez: 
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp6s2  proto static  metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp6s2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.86  metric 600 

ip addr sez:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0b:97:31:92:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp6s2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:ce:44:4c:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.86/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlp6s2
       valid_lft 85976sec preferred_lft 85976sec
    inet6 2602:306:358b:2df0:d81c:cace:8e01:5065/64 scope global

Comment: temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604375sec preferred_lft 85375sec
    inet6 2602:306:358b:2df0:f93e:83e5:406b:7a61/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 2591575sec preferred_lft 604375sec
    inet6 fe80::e107:e686:249:73e3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: Oh, and the connection is wireless as I'm in a motorhome...